# How easy is it to break this encryption system a buddy of mine and I just discovered?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, computer-science, cryptography, computational-mathematics

This is gonna take a little bit of background to explain, so here goes:

In base $11$, we have $11$ numerals to form numbers: $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9$, and since there is no single symbol standing for $10$, then we represent $10$ by the letter a. In base $16$, basically the same happens, but this time the "numerals" we have to work with are $0$ through $9$ and $a$ through $f$. You could do this all the way up to base $35$, where the numerals we would have to work with are $0$ through $9$ and the letters $a$ through $z$, where again $a$ stands for $10$ and z for $35$. Well, then, what if we wanted to work with bases greater than $35$? I looked it up and there was no standard convention for this so I made my own, which is the following: after $z$, our next numerals to work with will be a&, b&, ..., z&, where now a& will stand for $36$, b& for $37$ and so on. This does the job up until base $61$ of course. Now, to work with arbitrarily large integer positive bases, we keep adding the symbol & to the end of the letters, so a&& would stand for $62$, b&& for $63$ and so on. We can obviously keep doing this indefinitely.

Under this convention, the word "john" could represent basically any number. For example, in base $35$, the word "john" wound represent the number $844643$ in base $10$ (because j stands for $19$, o stands for $24$, h stands for $17$ and n stands for $23$ and $19 \cdot 35^3 + 24 \cdot 35^2 + 17 \cdot 35 + 23 \cdot 35^0 = 844643$). To illustrate another example, the number $844643$ in base $10$ can be represented under this convention in base $87$ as $\text{"1op&l&"}$, because $1 \cdot 87^3 + 24 \cdot 87^2 + 51 \cdot 87^1 + 47 \cdot 87^0 = 844643$, where again we have that o stands for $24$, "p&"  stands for $51$ and "l&" stands for $47$.

Therefore, you could define a function, let's call it encrypt, which takes three inputs (an initial base and a final base and a word) and returns an output of an encrypted word in return. For example, $\text{encrypt("john", 35, 87)}$ would equal $\text{"1op&l&"}$. With an initial base of $35$ and final base of $87$, the phrase "john smith has 5 bananas" would turn into $\text{"1op&l& d&&nt&&3 2h&&a&& 5 4ec&&9m&&i&&"}$. I have indeed defined such a function in Python which is how I know what these outputs are.

Then I thought "what if all I had to work with was the encrypted phrase, how would I go about deciphering it?". One could obviously brute force through as many possible initial and final bases as possible and that would eventually get me the original phrase. But brute force could also (conceivably, I'm not sure when that would actually happen) lead one to another reasonable phrase, such as "leopold ate 10 apples". And depending on how big the initial bases and final bases are and how big the original encrypted text is, I assume this could take a very long time. So this would be a very crude way of breaking the encryption which I want to exclude as a solution.

What other solutions to breaking this encryption are there? Since people always (with good reason) say never to use self-made encryption systems, I assume there is some way this would be trivially easy to break without resorting to brute force. Am I right?

Comment: This system isn't well specified because you haven't described how the two bases are chosen. That being said, are you really planning on using bases bigger than 10000 say, where digits require an average of about 200 ampersands each? And if both bases are less than 10000 then brute force is trivial.

Comment: @GregMartin you're right. But we could also create a personalized random alphabet (replacing a& with a random password of 8 characters and so on, for example) and randomize the initial and final bases (and the initial and final bases would be chosen at random from say 1 to a trillion) throughout the encryption so as to make brute force harder and frequency analysis useless. What other issues could arise then?

Comment: At that point, it seems like it's basically a one-time-pad where you use it multiple times, thus defeating the point of a one-time-pad.

Comment: @MichaelMorrow Thanks for replying, but why would it then be a one time pad used multiple times? The key would be the "passwords" corresponding to the symbols starting from $10$ (for example, replace a& with $\text{%a#MyJ@!}$) together with the bases used and the order they were used throughout the text. So the key would be a *single* tuple consisting of all of those passwords and values, meant to be used only one time just as the one time pad. So I think it would be basically a bona fide one-time-pad.

Comment: In practice, cryptographic ciphers should be resistant to chosen plaintext attacks. Suppose that an attacker has access to an encryption "black box" which uses your secret key to encrypt whatever the attacker feeds it, and the attacker attempts to figure out the secret key being used. This kind of cipher doesn't seem resistant to that. Also small changes to the input message lead to relatively small changes in the output, which is undesirable as it allows attackers to modify encrypted data in predictable ways.

Comment: @TobErnack I don't see how having a black box would help, I think the changes are not small. For example, without implenting the changes I proposed in the comments, encrypting "john" with initial bases 35 and 87 gives me "1op&l&" while encrypting "aohn", which is a change of a single letter, gives me "y&r&h". Encrypting "bohn" that way would give me "e&&o1". Why is that small? Changing the initial base to 36, "bohn" would give me "j&y&m&". If we replaced the symbols starting from 10 with a randomized alphabet like I said above I think it would be basically unbreakable

Comment: But if you try encrypting "joho"? Essentially your message is incremented by 1, and most cases this will change only a few a few least-significant "digits".

Comment: @TobErnack you're right. But this is easily fixed by randomizing the bases used in each letter of the message

Comment: If you *really* randomize the bases -- say, by rolling dice -- then you can easily write an unbreakable code. Also undecipherable by the intended recipient, unless the random data was shared with the recipient beforehand, in which case it's a one-time pad, which also is essentially unbreakable. The rest is then window dressing.

Comment: @DavidK Getting a system as "unbreakable" as the one time pad is as far as I wanted to get, even if this is way more impractical than the one-time pad. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: The "unbreakable" system is the system you described in the question **plus** a one-time pad for the "random" bases. The unbreakability comes from the pad, not necessarily from the base-conversion system. In fact, if you really wanted to be sure about the combined system, you'd want to confirm that the added gimmick of the base conversion doesn't inadvertently give clues about the one-time pad.